How to successfully request this endpoint?
I am trying to scrape this website, I have checked the robots.txt and according to my understanding, they allow the scraping of the website.
No matter how much I try, fiddle with the headers, simulate browser behaviour, everything, but I could not get a <200> status code.
The website is https://www.mastersportal.com/universities/80/tilburg-university.html the network tab shows trivial headers, there are no cookies passed according to my understanding, but still the servers deny the request.
I would appreciate if someone could tell me the correct way to scrape the site, I do not want to use selenium as it defeats the key requirement which is speed.

If you look at the response headers (in your browser) you will see that Server is cloudflare There are non-standard modules available that may help you to bypass that line of defence.

@SIGHUP Thank you very much man, I used the cloudscraper library and it worked! Thanks again for not being toxic like most of the people here are.
